# ajax call fails only on Android 4.1 + Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developping an app with Phonegap Build (phonegap 3.3). I am doing an ajax call (jsonp) to retrieve a file and it works, except on android 4.1.
I am seeing there is a new thing on Android 4 : getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs...is that the problem ? Is this a Phonegap bug ?

Thanks

JS:

```
      return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           jsonpCallback: "callback",
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           timeout: 15000,
           success: function() {
            console.log("getJsonpFile ajax is successful");
          },
           error: function(xOptions, textStatus) {
            console.log("problem with ajax jsonp request in getJsonpFile");
            console.log("xOptions :");
            console.log(xOptions);
            console.log("textStatus :"+textStatus);
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be an issue with Phonegap and Android 4.1 [see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/PhoneGap/wdQ4ga5Lkp0).

The solution is to use a basic XMLHTTPRequest as shown [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.fr/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html).

It worked in my case.